# Change colour of rows for highest value in table

Tags: php, html

I have created a simple html table within PHP. Here is my code:

```
  <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="chart">
            <h2>Files Uploaded to Knowledge Base</h2>
            <table id="data-table" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">


            <tr id=header>
                    <td>Users</td>
                    <td id=center>Project Files</td>
                    <td id=center>Process Files</td>
                    <td id=center>System Files</td>
                    <td id=center>Total Files</td>
            </tr>   

                        <?php

                        $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('upload/project/');
                        foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {

                        $pos = 15;
                        $file = substr("$filename", +$pos); 

                        $lenght = strlen($file);
                        $pos = strpos($file, "/");
                        $file = substr("$file",0,$pos);
                        if($file1 != '.DS_Store'){

                            $serverfiles = mysql_query("SELECT uploader FROM Project WHERE location = '$file'");

                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($serverfiles)) {
                                $occurance1 = $row['uploader'];
                                $array1[] = $occurance1; 
                                }
                            }                           
                        }




                        $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('upload/process/');
                        foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {

                        $pos = 15;
                        $file = substr("$filename", +$pos);                         
                        $lenght = strlen($file);
                        $pos = strpos($file, "/");
                        $file = substr("$file",0,$pos);

                        if($file != '.DS_Store'){

                            $serverfiles = mysql_query("SELECT uploader FROM Process WHERE processlocation = '$file'");

                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($serverfiles)) {
                                $occurance2 = $row['uploader'];
                                $array2[] = $occurance2; 
                                }
                            }                           
                        }

                        $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('upload/system/');
                        foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {

                        $pos = 14;
                        $file = substr("$filename", +$pos);                         
                        $lenght = strlen($file);
                        $pos = strpos($file, "/");
                        $file = substr("$file",0,$pos);
                        if($file != '.DS_Store'){

                            $serverfiles = mysql_query("SELECT uploader FROM System WHERE location = '$file'");

                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($serverfiles)) {
                                $occurance3 = $row['uploader'];
                                $array3[] = $occurance3; 
                                }
                            }                           
                        }

                        $table_rows = array();
                        $counter = 0;
                        $uploader = mysql_query("Select username from members");
                        while($Load = mysql_fetch_array($uploader)){
                        $value = $Load['username'];

                        $tmp = array_count_values($array1);
                        $cnt = $tmp[$value];

                        $tmp2 = array_count_values($array2);
                        $cnt2 = $tmp2[$value];

                        $tmp3 = array_count_values($array3);
                        $cnt3 = $tmp3[$value];

                        $total = $cnt + $cnt2 + $cnt3;

                        //putting the values into array
                        $counter++;
                        $table_rows[$counter] = array();
                        $table_rows[$counter]['username'] = $value;
                        $table_rows[$counter]['project'] = $cnt;
                        $table_rows[$counter]['process'] = $cnt2;
                        $table_rows[$counter]['system'] = $cnt3;
                        $table_rows[$counter]['total'] = $total;
                        }

                        //function to sort the highest total value
                        function cmp_rows($a,$b) {
                        if ($a['total'] == $b['total']) {
                        return 0;
                        }
                        return ($a['total'] > $b['total']) ? -1 : 1;
                        }

                        usort($table_rows, 'cmp_rows');

                        //loop that prints values
                        foreach($table_rows as $row) {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>{$row['username']}</td>";
                        echo"<td id=center>{$row['project']}</td>";
                        echo"<td id=center>{$row['process']}</td>";
                        echo "<td id=center>{$row['system']}</td>";
                        echo "<td id=center>{$row['total']}</td>";
                        }


                        ?>

            </table>

    </div>

    </body></html>
```

The users are populated from a database table. The file figures are populated by reading and counting the amount of files in the directory. The table is sorted by highest first. I would like the first, second and third rows to be a different colour than the rest.

I do not know how to do this. Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a key to the foreach then create a simple if/else statement when you output the table row that says:

```
> foreach( $table_rows as $key => $row ) {
>     if ( $key < 3 ) { 
>       echo "<tr style="background color here">; 
>     } 
>     else { 
>       echo "<tr>";
>     }
>     //Rest of Code Here }
```

Comment: Fixed, didn't read through the code above the output and just put the counter there in case the array he was looping through had defined keys that weren't 1,2,3...

Comment: Ah, it's $key => $value I always mess these two up